# Jquery UI autocomplete with pictures in Django

Tags: django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have ab autocomplete enabled in my Django project. It works fine. But I would like to add pictures to the suggestions. I tried the official docs but information is parsed:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

My JS:

```
$(function(){    
  $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {      
      item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:#C45525'>$1</span>");
      return $("<li></li>")
              .data("item.autocomplete", item)
              .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
  };     
  $('.prod2').autocomplete({
    open: function() { $('.ui-menu').width(350);
} ,
    source: '/finder/search_auto',
    minLength: 3,       
});    
  });
```

My view:

```
  def search_auto(request):
    if request.is_ajax():    
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    products = Product.objects.filter(real_name__icontains=q)    
    results = []
    for pr in products:
        product_json = {'value':0, 'image':0, 'label':0}
        product_json['value'] = pr.real_name
        product_json['label'] = pr.real_name
        product_json['img'] = pr.picture               
        results.append(product_json)
    print (results)
    data = json.dumps(results)
  else:
    data = 'fail'
  mimetype = 'application/json'
  return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

I can't figure out how to pass my product picture url into my `data`an how to display it.

Comment: Please provide an example response to the GET request. I don't see where `data` would contain the URL, it seems to only contain `pr.real_name`. I also do not see where you configure `_renderItems` in your example.

Comment: I edited my question JS because I have implemented suggestion high lightening meanwhile I was stuck on the picture implementation.
My data only contains `pr.real_name` for now. I tried  `product_json = pr.real_name + pr.picture` but the result was a concatenated string of my product name and its picture's url in the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my JS this way and it works as it should:

```
$(function() {
  $('.prod2').autocomplete({
    open: function() {
      $('.ui-menu').width(350);
    },
    source: '/finder/search_auto',
    minLength: 3,
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:#C45525'>$1</span>");
    return $("<li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<div><img src='" + item.img + "' height='55' /> " + item.label + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your view, consider the following:

```
def search_auto(request):
  if request.is_ajax():    
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    products = Product.objects.filter(real_name__icontains=q)    
    results = []
    for pr in products:
      product_json = {}
      product_json.label = pr.real_name
      products_json.value = pr.real_name
      products_json.image = pr.picture
      results.append(product_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
  else:
    data = 'fail'
  mimetype = 'application/json'
  return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

This should result in an Array of Objects passed back to the AJAX in JSON.

```
[{
  "label": "John Smith",
  "value": "John Smith",
  "image": "./img/jsmith.jpg"
}]
```

Now you can make use of these details in Autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
  $('.prod2').autocomplete({
    open: function() {
      $('.ui-menu').width(350);
    },
    source: '/finder/search_auto',
    minLength: 3,
  })._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<div><img src='" + item.image + "' /> " + item.label + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I don't get any Array of Objects, instead a 
`product_json.label = pr.real_name
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'label'` error.

Comment: I have updated my view.py so now I get `[{
  "label": "John Smith",
  "value": "John Smith",
  "image": "./img/jsmith.jpg"
}]` But it doesn't work either

Comment: @HomeAlone please review the Console and Network and provide a example of the payload being sent back to AJAX.